Dialog custom state on windowBackground?
Is it possible to let my android:windowBackground drawable receive custom attributes I added?
For backgrounds I have custom Views on that I can override the onCreateDrawableState. For Dialogs that's not possible. Is there a way to work around?
What do I do?
I have two custom attributes which are used as a state in my drawables (like android:state_pressed="true")
<attr name="state_light" format="boolean"/>
<attr name="state_dark" format="boolean"/>

My MainActivity has variable val foo: Boolean. When the value is changed I call refreshDrawableState on the following ViewGroups and their children to trigger an onCreateDrawableState

window.decorView
dialog.window.decorView

In all of my Views I now override the onCreateDrawableState so I can add the custom state
override fun onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace: Int): IntArray {
    val state = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1)
    return when (mainActivity.foo) {
        true -> state.mergeDrawableState(attr.state_light)
        false -> state.mergeDrawableState(attr.state_dark)
    }
}

Now I create and set a drawable onto a specific View (somewhere in my tree) that itself has a Selector with my items that listen for my custom states.
<selector>
    <item android:color="#ffffff" app:state_light="true"/>
    <item android:color="#000000" app:state_dark="true"/>
    <item android:color="#323232"/>
</selector>

The top code works fine and I can switch colors in my app via the foo value. This just does not work for android:windowBackground. I need to use the windowBackground as I have to use the full API (like setPositiveButton).
My guess is that Android internal has an onCreateDrawableState that is not in my reach. I am just out of ideas and seek for some inspiration/help. Thanks in advance.

If you have custom views just use setView() of AlertDialog

Interesting idea but that does not solve my issue with windowBackground. I need to support positiveButton and other apis. I will be more specific in my question.
